# Was it Faith or Fabric that healed the sick woman in Luke 8:44-46?

Tags: luke

In **Luke 8:44-46** [NIV], we read about a Sick Woman who touches the cloak of Jesus & miraculously becomes healed :

> [44] She came up behind him and touched the edge of his cloak, and immediately her bleeding stopped.
>
> [45] “Who touched me?” Jesus asked. When they all denied it, Peter said, “Master, the people are crowding and pressing against you.”
>
> [46] But Jesus said, “Someone touched me; I know that power has gone out from me.”

**Was it Faith or Fabric that healed the sick woman in Luke 8:44-46?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jesus answers this question Himself in Luke 8:48 -

> 48“Daughter,” said Jesus, “your faith has healed you. Go in peace.”

We have the same thing in Matt 9:22 -

> 22 Jesus turned and saw her. “Take courage, daughter,” He said, “your
> faith has healed you.” And the woman was cured from that very hour.

Again, in Mark 5:34 -

> 34 “Daughter,” said Jesus, “your faith has healed you. Go in peace and
> be free of your affliction.”

The miraculous cure of the woman was healed the same way that the daughter of Jairus was healed - the power of God grasped by the "hand" of faith.  Jesus effectively says to this woman who has suffered for 12 years, "your faith has healed you"; that is, if her faith had not ben enough to drive her to do something illegal under Torah law (her bleeding made her an outcast) then no healing would have occurred!

Thus, Jesus says that her actions, impelled by faith healed the woman because she reached out for the divine cure.  In commenting upon the parallel passage in Matt 9:22 we have the Cambridge commentary:

> 22. thy faith hath made thee whole] Rather, “thy faith hath saved thee,” and not the external act of touching my garment. True
>     faith—spiritual insight—will be accepted by Jesus in spite of
>     ignorance.

Ellicott also comments:

> The teaching of the narrative lies almost on the surface. There may be
> imperfect knowledge, false shame, imperfect trust, and yet if the germ
> of faith be there, Christ, the Healer both of the souls and bodies of
> men, recognises even the germ, and answers the longing desire of the
> soul to be freed from its uncleanness. Other healers may have been
> sought in vain, but it finds its way through the crowd that seems to
> hinder its approach, and the “virtue” which it seeks goes forth even
> from the “hem of the garment,” even through outward ordinances (for
> thus we interpret the miracle, which is also a parable), which in
> themselves have no healing power.